# angular.js: reference the current model by short variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

suppose I am binding to a model using a long expression such as

```
 <ul class="container" ui-sortable  ng-model="cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-    color']" ng-class="{selected: cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-color'] ==    selectedCategory}" ng-click="selectCategory(cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-color'])">
```

is there a way to not repeat cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-color'],

and just bind to the currently referenced model using some keyword or assigned variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with ng-init :

```
 <ul 
     class="container"
     ui-sortable
     ng-init="mymodel = cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-color']"
     ng-model=""
     ng-class="{selected: mymodel  ==    selectedCategory}"
     ng-click="selectCategory(mymodel )"
>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, this works. though I have decided not to use use it because it does not seem to work well with https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you expose it trough the `controller` like:

```
$scope.cssCategory = cssRules.categories['sd-text-highlight-color']
```

**[UPDATE]**

With regards to `ng-init` alternative (from Angular documentation):

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties
>   of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialise values on a scope.

[More info](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

This might be a reason that it doesn't work well with `ui-sortable` so I guess this approach should be avoided.

Comment: I have dozens of these. I am not sure if it makes sense to write the boilerplate for each one.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Is a relatively small amount of coding on the controller compared to the savings that it yields in the view.